# How to convert csv to xml using Hive UDF or Pig UDF?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, talend, udf

I am trying to convert a csv file to xml using Hive or Pig.

When I google I see lot of solutions where we are parsing xml to get csv but not the other way around. Can someone help me?

Right now we are doing this using a tool called Talend, but that is not a good solution because it is using the execution server instead of cluster.

```
eid,ename,sal
1,a,d1
2,b,d2
3,c,d3
```

to

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Employee_Info
  <Employee  eid="1">
  <Name>a</Name>
  <Department>d1</Department>
</Employee>
  <Employee  eid=2>
  <Name>b</Name>
  <Department>d2</Department>
</Employee>
<Employee  eid=3>
  <Name>c</Name>
  <Department>d3</Department>
</Employee>
</Employee_Info>
```

Comment: Why would you do want to convert a csv to xml? Not a good idea to use Pig to transform csv to xml.

Comment: Only reason I feel you want to use pig/hive is that your datasize is huge. If that is the case implement UDF to do this. Your UDF code should look something like this :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786207/java-convert-pipe-and-comma-delimited-file-into-xml

Comment: Thank you very much @sorabh, indeed the data size is big and if I dont use a big data component, it will be a bottleneck

Comment: @inquisitive-mind --> we need to transform the data to a model called ECMM which is an xml format. But our data is in hive views so we need to convert that data to xmls

Comment: @Acharya stackoverflow link I mentioned above seems to be pretty good. If you are writing UDF in java and face any issues, do update me